# How can I remove columns without specific headers?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA macro for excel to remove columns I don't have specific headers for. I have come close but have run into an odd problem with the way the columns remove.

I am using a simple nested IF. The odd thing is when I run my code it only removes every OTHER column that is not in my list. I have to run the macro 4 or 5 times to get the wanted result. This code is meant to be part of a larger macro and will be for other users as well so getting it to work right the first time is key.

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
Set MR = Range("A1:W1")
For Each cell In MR
    If cell.Value <> "Cartons" Then
        If cell.Value <> "ShipVia" Then
            If cell.Value <> "Name" Then
                If cell.Value <> "Address" Then
                    If cell.Value <> "City" Then
                        If cell.Value <> "State" Then
                            If cell.Value <> "Zip" Then
                                cell.EntireColumn.Delete
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your Problem

The issue you are seeing is due to the fact that you are deleting columns inside your loop range. When you delete a column, the range you are looping through shifts and this causes columns to be skipped (consistent with your results). To combat this, you can use the `Union` method which allows you to delete columns outside of the loop so you will not experience the reported issue. The bottom solution shows how to fix the reported issue if you do decide to delete columns inside the loop.

---

### Select Case

`Select Case` would be my preferred method. Loop through the range and if the cell is not in listed in the first case, it will be flagged to be deleted in the second case (`Case Else`).

Once you have looped your headers, delete the columns all at once which means there is no range shift while looping.

```
Sub DeleteColumns()

Dim iCell As Range, DeleteMe As Range

For Each iCell In Range("A1:W1")
    Select Case iCell
        Case "Cartons", "ShipVia", "Name", "Address", "City", "State", "Zip"
            'Do Nothing
        Case Else
            If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
                Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, iCell)
            Else
                Set DeleteMe = iCell
            End If
    End Select
Next iCell

If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then DeleteMe.EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

---

### Array

You could also loop through an array. Note that the column loop is going backwards to stop the relevant range from shifting inside the loop (your initial problem). To do this, you will need to drop the `For Each` loop and switch to the `For j = # - #` so you can utilize the `Step -1` property

```
Sub Array_Method()

Dim Arr: Arr = Array("Cartons", "ShipVia", "Name", "Address", "City", "State", "Zip")
Dim i As Long, j As Long

For j = 23 To 1 Step -1
    For i = UBound(Arr) To LBound(Arr)
        If Arr(i) = Cells(1, j) Then
            Cells(1, j).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Great answer! I'd like to add that OP could possibly benefit from something like a `LastCol` variable, in the event that they're getting an inconsistent amount of columns that they have to get rid of it on their worksheets...

Comment: True. I re-read and the post sounds repetitive so I will prob edit the explanation later and add dynamic loop. Good suggestion @dwirony

Comment: Thank you so much. This was a much more elegant way to solve my macro. I appreciate you explaining where my issue was coming from too.

Comment: In your select case method, can you explain what the Union is doing? I get the concept of it being the intersecting things, but i suppose the `If not DeleteMe is Nothing` is confusing me. Why do you set it equal to `iCell`?

Comment: `Union` is a collection of cells. The `Set DeleteMe = iCell` will only be ran once (the very first time a range does not meet any of the case statements). The rest of the time we will create a collection by continuously adding onto the newly found variable `DeleteMe`

Comment: @MarkS. Since `DeleteMe` is a variable type `Range`, you have to make sure the range actually has something assigned to it (otherwise the variable is equal to `Nothing`). I am using the double negative at the end to make sure the variable is NOT `Nothing`. You can not delete `Nothing` or modify it  as this will produce errors. Trying to do *something* to *nothing* makes no sense :)

Comment: So how are you assigning the things not in `iCell` to `Deleteme`. The code works but I'm trying to decode how it's working.

Comment: So this code wants to know when a cell does not have a target value. Which means when the code is done, the `Union` (collection) will have all cells that do not equal target. I am calling this `DeleteMe`. The first time a cell is found that does not equal a target value, we will assign that individual cell to the `DeleteMe` range since it is only ONE value, not a collection. Every time after, when we add cells we will be creating a collection. This is why I check that `Not DeleteMe is Nothing`. @MarkS.

Comment: @MarkS. `DeleteMe` is only assigned inside the `Case Else` statement. All we need to know is if we have a single cell or a collection of cells. You will only have a single cell once after all, which is why I put this as the last test. You could swap the logic and it would make more sense although less efficient. Just step through the code using F8 with a sample set. You will notice the pattern ;P

Answer (score 0):

*@urdearboy* is absolutely correct in his diagnosis of the problem. Here is my solution as a variation on the theme of `Select Case` which happens to be an approach that is both compact and very descriptive (readable).

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim i As Long

    LastCol = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:W1").Cells.Count
    i = 1
    Do
        Select Case ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i)
        Case "Cartons", "ShipVia", "Name", "Address", "City", "State", "Zip"
            i = i + 1 ' this column is to remain; examine the next column
        Case Else
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
            LastCol = LastCol - 1 ' as you delete columns the right margin moves in
            ' do not increment "i" because the next column moves in place automatically
        End Select
    Loop Until i > LastCol
End Sub
```

Hope this helps to illustrate the "mechanics" of column deletion.

To have more efficiency in the code (in light of the above) we need to start from the right so that only one "positional" variable is required:

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim i As Long

    i= ActiveSheet.Range("A1:W1").Cells.Count
    Do
        Select Case ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i)
        Case Is <> "Cartons", "ShipVia", "Name", "Address", "City", "State", "Zip"
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End Select
        i = i - 1 
    Loop While i > 0
End Sub
```

And, of course, this can be easily generalized for the situations when, for example, the range does not start in column "A", etc.