# VBA to delete columns in Excel using specific headers with wild cards

Tags: excel, vba

I need to begin pulling a quarterly export of data that has nearly 300 columns. I then want to use a VBA macro to clean up the columns I don't need, as there are a lot of useless ones.

I've found a pretty good VBA in a thread on here that almost works perfectly for me:

[How can I remove columns without specific headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261161/how-can-i-remove-columns-without-specific-headers)

However, my issue is that this data is imported from an XML and the headers are not always static. They always have some constant value in the name, for example, "HostID" but then there are 20 different "HostID" headers. All followed by a random number. Such as "HostID154".

I'm hoping to find a way to loop through the columns and keep all columns with headers named like whatever I need to keep. I just don't know how to apply a wild card to this scenario using case.

```vb
Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim i As Long

    LastCol = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:KZ1").Cells.Count
    i = 1
    Do
        Select Case ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i)
        Case "Name", "HostID", "Path", "ID"
            i = i + 1 ' this column is to remain; examine the next column
        Case Else
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
            LastCol = LastCol - 1 ' as you delete columns the right margin moves in
            ' do not increment "i" because the next column moves in place automatically
        End Select
    Loop Until i > LastCol
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim LastCol As Long, ws As Worksheet, nm
    Dim i As Long, hdr As String, del As Boolean
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    LastCol = ws.Range("KZ1").Column
    For i = LastCol To 1 Step -1
        hdr = Trim(ws.Cells(1, i).Value)
        If Len(hdr) > 0 Then
            del = True
            For Each nm In Array("Name", "HostID", "Path", "ID")
                If InStr(1, hdr, nm, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then 'does `hdr` begin with text `nm`?
                    del = False 'keep this column
                    Exit For    'stop checking
                End If
            Next nm
            If del Then ws.Columns(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete columns in reverse order to avoid the cells shifting and change of columns count.

`Case` doesn't support `Like` operator.

```vb
Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim LastCol As Long, j As Integer
    Dim i As Long, bCon As Boolean, sTxt
    LastCol = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:KZ1").Cells.Count
    For i = LastCol To 1 Step -1
        sTxt = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i)
        bCon = (sTxt Like "Name*") Or (sTxt Like "HostID*") Or _
            (sTxt Like "Path*") Or (sTxt Like "ID*")
        If Not bCon Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```